# Magento 2 - Send form data to Controller using AJAX

Tags: magento2

So im building a simple widget - that sends contact data though ajax to controller. But it is not working im getting a **Uncaught Error: Call to a member function create() on null in**

**Layout - Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/ContactFormular_index_post.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <title>Kontakt Formular</title>
</head> 
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Ereactor\ContactFormular\Block\Widget\KontaktFormular" before="-" template="Ereactor_ContactFormular::KontaktFormular.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

**PHTML -Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/widget/KontaktFormular.phtml**

```
<form id="contactForm" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="receiver_email_address" value="<?=$block->getData('Email') ?>">
        <div class="card bg-light border-0 rounded-0 mb-5 p-3">
            <div class="card-body mb-3">
                <div id="messages_product_view"></div>
                <p class="card-text font-weight-bold">Book et møte med oss</p>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-11 col-lg-6">
                        <div class="field mb-3">
                            <div class="input-box">
                                <label class="mb-1 ml-2" for="name">Navn</label>
                                <input placeholder="Fornavn Etternavn" name="name" id="name" title="Navn" value="" class="input-text form-control required-entry p-3" type="text">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field mb-3">
                            <div class="input-box">
                                <label class="mb-1 ml-2" for="email">E-post</label>
                                <input placeholder="E-post" name="email" id="email" title="Epost" value="" class="input-text form-control required-entry validate-email p-3" type="text">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field mb-3">
                            <div class="input-box">
                                <label class="mb-1 ml-2" for="telephone">Telefonnummer</label>
                                <input placeholder="Telefonnummer" name="telephone" id="telephone" title="Telefon" class="input-text form-control required-entry p-3" type="text">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <label class="mb-1 ml-2" for="comment">Melding</label>
                            <textarea placeholder="Skriv her" name="comment" id="comment" title="Kommentar" class="required-entry input-text form-control p-3" cols="5" rows="10"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer bg-light border-0 p-0 position-absolute text-center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning mb-n3">Send</button>
            </div>
        </div></form><script>require(['jquery'],function(){
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#contactForm").submit(function(){

        var name = jQuery("input[name='name']").val();
        var email = jQuery("input[name='email']").val();
        var telephone = jQuery("input[name='telephone']").val();
        var comment = jQuery("input[name='comment']").val();

        jQuery.ajax({
        url : 'ContactFormular/index/post',
        type: "POST",
        data: {name:name, email:email, telephone:telephone, comment:comment},
        showLoader: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response.output);
        }
        
    });
    return false;
    });
}); });
```

**Block - Vendor/Module/Block/Widget/KontaktFormular.php**

```
    <?php
namespace Ereactor\ContactFormular\Block\Widget;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Widget\Block\BlockInterface;

class KontaktFormular extends Template implements BlockInterface
{
protected $_template = "widget/KontaktFormular.phtml";


public function getName()
{
    return $this->getName();
}

public function getEmail()
{
    return $this->getEmail();
}

public function getTelephone()
{
    return $this->getTelephone();
}

public function getComment()
{
    return $this->getComment();
}

}
```

**Controller - Vendor/Module/Controller/Index/Post.php**

```
    <?php

namespace Ereactor\ContactFormular\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Post extends Action {

     protected $resultJsonFactory;

    public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory) 
    {           
       $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory; 
       return parent::__construct($context);
    }


    public function execute() {
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json $result */
    $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
    return $result->setData(['success' => true]);
   } 
}
```

The workflow - user comes on KontaktFormular.phtml page > enters input > call submit > sends the data. Just for now.

- While trying to call controller action using AJAX, it is not working im getting this error

> [20-Aug-2020 08:47:53 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory::create() must be of the type array, string given, called in /home/clean/public_html/magento2/submodules/ContactFormular/Controller/Index/Post.php on line 25 and defined in /home/clean/public_html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Controller/Result/JsonFactory.php:48
> Stack trace:
> #0 /home/clean/public_html/magento2/submodules/ContactFormular/Controller/Index/Post.php(25): Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory->create('json')
> #1 /home/clean/public_html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(108): Ereactor\ContactFormular\Controller\Index\Post->execute()
> #2 /home/clean/public_html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
> #3 /home/clean/public_html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Ereactor\ContactFormular\Controller\Index\Post\Interceptor->___callP in /home/clean/public_html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Controller/Result/JsonFactory.php on line 48

Answer (score 0):

Please run

**php bin/magento setup:upgrade**

It will be fixed.